# Is there any way to invert file selections on Mac OS X like we do it on Windows?

Tags: macos, finder

I'm Windows OS lover but recently I've got Mac Notebook as a gift. So now I just want to know if is there any option under *Edit* that lets me invert my selection? For example, I select only files that I don’t want and once I click on *Invert Selection* using *Edit* option, all the files that I didn’t select will be selected instead.

Is there any similar option in OS X too?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The key you're looking for is <kbd>Cmd</kbd>.

Select the files – any view should work – then move with the mouse cursor to the empty space next to the file list. Hold <kbd>Cmd</kbd> and drag to invert the selection:

[image]

---

If you don't want to use the mouse, an alternative way would be to use AppleScript instead. Open up *Automator.app*, create a new *Service*. From the left pane, drag *Run AppleScript* to the right, and paste the following:*

```
on run {input, parameters}

  tell application "Finder"
    set inverted to {}
    set fitems to items of window 1 as alias list
    set selectedItems to the selection as alias list
    repeat with i in fitems
      if i is not in selectedItems then
        set end of inverted to i
      end if
    end repeat
    select inverted
  end tell

  return input
end run
```

Set this service to receive *No Input* from *Finder.app*. Like this:

[image]

Save this service as *Invert Selection*. Then, head to *System Preferences » Keyboard » Keyboard Shortcuts*, and add your shortcut to the service, for example <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>I</kbd>:

[image]

Now, select any files in Finder and press the shortcut to invert the selection.

<sub>* I found this on the [Apple Mailing Lists](http://lists.apple.com/archives/applescript-users/2009/Dec/msg00301.html), no idea who wrote it though.</sub>

Comment: If the script is run after opening a new window, it usually selects all files because of [this bug](http://www.openradar.me/9406282).

Comment: Your script does not scale all to well. Works fine for a folder with <50 items, but for a folder with 1500 items it resulted in a timeout :-( **My use case**: I made aliases to desired files within a folder of 1500 files. I select all aliases, press CMD-R (reveal originals), and then would like to invert the selection, to then erase the needless files. **Workaround**: Move the selection into a temporary folder, delete the remaining undesired files, move the desired files back.

Comment: @porg Well, who has 1500 items in a folder! :) But yeah, AppleScripts don't scale that well, you're right.

Comment: Would there be a possibility to save the items as a something less resource intensive than an alias list, i.e. a POSIX file list or the like?

Comment: The `cmd` trick is awesome.

Comment: I have tried this solution on Yosemite 10.10. The script is working but can't use this keyboard shortcut as it conflicts with the built-in iCloud keyboard shortcut. I have tried many other keyboard shortcut but couldn't run the script as a service.

Comment: You have to write a script and do all this crap on a mac to do something as mundane as inverting a selection? Which is really common because you could have a folder of 5000 pictures, and you perhaps just want to keep 5 of them?

Comment: Testing the Cmd trick on Catalina 15.7 and Monterey 12.3 Beta (happens to be what I'm running). **In List view** (as shown above) when doing the click-and-drag, **you must start on one of the files** (i.e., not below the list, which de-selects everything), **and not on the `Name` field** (which initiates a drag and drop). Dragging to the right of the fields (i.e., where no field is displayed) works, but isn't required

Answer (score 0):

On windows there is another way to do this.

[image: invert select]

It should work for Mac too.

Comment: This doesn't work. If you hold `ctrl` and click, it will pop up the context menu, since `ctrl`-click emulates a secondary mouse button.

Comment: Parasanth's answer does actually work on mac, you just swap ctrl for cmd

Comment: doesn't work and it seems not workable all the time

Answer (score -1):

It's not quite the same, but there's a more natural way to do this sort of thing on a Mac: rather than selecting the files you don't want and then inverting the selection, select all files (Edit menu > Select All, or Command-A), then deselect the files you don't want with Command-click.

Comment: I can confirm that this does not work on Catalina 15.1.3 at least.